# How to implement two-way data binding inbetween a DataGrid and the fields of a class T contained by a List<T>?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a the following DataGrid in my XAML.

```
<DataGrid 
                ItemsSource="{Binding SomeClassInstance.SomeList, Mode=TwoWay}">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                
                                <CheckBox
                                    IsChecked="{Binding ShouldInclude, Mode="TwoWay"}"/>
                                
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Where `SomeList` is a field with type `ObservableCollection<SomeClass>`, where `SomeClass` has the field `ShouldInclude` which is a bool.

I wish to establish two-way data binding inbetween each member of `SomeList` and the checkboxes of the DataGrid, so that when I check/uncheck a CheckBox in the DataGrid, the corresponding class instance of the list will have its `ShouldInclude` field set to true/false.

The field `SomeList` looks like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<SomeClass> _someList;
        public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> SomeList
        {
            get
            {
                return _someList;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _someList)
                {
                    _someList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeList));

                }
            }
        }
```

The class `SomeClass` has a field `ShouldInclude` that looks like this.

```
private bool _shouldInclude;
        public bool ShouldInclude
        {
            get
            {
                return _shouldInclude;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _shouldInclude)
                {
                    _shouldInclude = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShouldInclude));
                }
            }
        }
```

I added a `Debug.WriteLine` to the setter of `ShouldInclude`, and it only gets accessed by the constructor of the `SomeClass`.

To me, this indicates that the class itself is properly set up, but that something in the XAML data binding is not implemented properly. I just don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the binding to `PropertyChanged` to trigger the setter as soon as you check or uncheck the `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShouldInclude,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```